# how to disable the automatic center in gojs diagram?

Tags: gojs

The first click on the diagram causes the automatic positioning of the page in the center of the same, how is it disabled? how can I fix it?
I can't find a documentation for these problem.
goJs version 2.0.9
we have integrated gojs with angular js these are the functions called after two bees that retrieve nodes and links

```
$scope.createCustomNode = function () {
            var nodePicture = $scope.make(
                $go.Picture,
                {maxSize: new go.Size(475, 166)},
                new $go.Binding("source", "src")
            )
            var nodeTesxt = $scope.make(
                $go.TextBlock,
                "Default Text",
                new go.Binding("stroke", "color"),
                {margin: 12, font: "21px sans-serif"},
                new $go.Binding('text', 'name')
            )
            var managedEvent = {
                click: function (e, obj) {
                    $scope.nodeClick(obj.part.data.key)
                },
            }
            $scope.diagram.nodeTemplate = $scope.make(
                $go.Node,
                managedEvent,
                new $go.Binding("location", "loc", $go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay($go.Point.stringify),
                'Vertical',
                {background: 'transparent'},
                nodePicture,
                nodeTesxt
            )
        }
        $scope.createCustomLink = function () {
            var linkStyle = $scope.make(
                $go.Shape,
                new go.Binding("stroke", "color"),
                new go.Binding("strokeWidth", "width"),
                new go.Binding("strokeDashArray", "dash")
            )
            var startTextLink = $scope.make(
                $go.TextBlock,
                {font: "18px sans-serif"},
                new $go.Binding('text', 'startLabel'),
                {
                    segmentIndex: 0,
                    segmentFraction: 0.2,
                    segmentOffset: new go.Point(0, -20)
                }
            )
            var endTextLink = $scope.make(
                $go.TextBlock,
                {font: "18px sans-serif"},
                new $go.Binding('text', 'endLabel'),
                {
                    segmentIndex: 0,
                    segmentFraction: 0.8,
                    segmentOffset: new go.Point(0, -20)
                }
            )
            $scope.diagram.linkTemplate = $scope.make(
                $go.Link,
                linkStyle,
                startTextLink,
                endTextLink
            )
        }
        $scope.createDiagram = function () {
            $scope.diagram.model = $scope.model
        }
        $scope.initDiagramParams = function () {
            $scope.diagram = $scope.make($go.Diagram, 'diagram', {
                initialAutoScale: $go.Diagram.Uniform,
                // layout: new $go.ForceDirectedLayout(),
                // layout: new $go.LayeredDigraphLayout(),
                allowCopy: false
            })
            $scope.diagram.addDiagramListener('SelectionMoved', function (e) {
                $scope.nodeDragEnd(e)
            })
        }
```

Comment: Which version of GoJS are you using?  (Evaluate `go.version`.)  How do you initialize your diagram beyond what you have shown in your code?

Comment: 2.0.9, I start the diagram, I call the API to have nodes and links and on the answer I pass the data to the diagram

Comment: Do you create a Model and set the Diagram.model?

Comment: yes, function createDiagram.was call after API for node and link

Answer (score 1):

Try setting **Diagram.initialContentAlignment** in your Diagram initializations.  For example:

```
$(go.Diagram, . . .,
  {
    initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.TopLeft,
    initialAutoScale: go.Diagram.Uniform,
    layout: . . .
  })
```

If you do not specify the **initialContentAlignment**, or the **initialDocumentSpot** and **initialViewportSpot**, or the **initialPosition**, the default behavior in version 2.0 is to center the content in the viewport.  The default behavior in version 1.* was to put the content at the top-left of the viewport.